# Expectation of inverse of sum of iid random variables - approximation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expectation

I am working with the set of i.i.d *discrete* random variables $\{\zeta_1, \ldots, \zeta_n\}$. Each one of them can take either of the $m$ values $\{z_1, \ldots, z_m\}$ with corresponding probabilities $\{p_1, \ldots , p_m\}$.

I am trying to understand when I can apply the following approximation for the expectation (which I believe to be the first-order one):
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\min\left(A, \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^n \mathrm{I}[\zeta_k\geq \bar{z}]}\right)\right] \approx \min\left(A, \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^n \mathrm{I}[\zeta_k\geq \bar{z}]\right]}\right)
\end{equation}

Here $A$ and $\bar{z}$-- are some constants and an indicator function $\mathrm{I}[\zeta_k\geq \bar{z}]=1$ if $\zeta_k\geq \bar{z}$ and $0$ otherwise.

I am working in the regime $n\to\infty$ and the question is *whether the approximation above is good enough under this condition?* (if it is possible to judge, though)

I checked the following [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302436/expectation-of-inverse-of-sum-of-random-variables), however I am not sure how to make use of $\mathcal{L}_{X(t)}^n$ under large $n$ in the case of discrete distribution.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p=P(\zeta\ge z)$. Then as $n\to\infty$ $$LHS\approx E(\frac 1 {B(n,p)};B(n,p)\ge 1)\approx \frac 1 {np}+\frac {np(1-p)}{(np)^3}=\frac 1 {np}+\frac {1-p}{(np)^2}=\frac 1{np}(1+\frac{1-p}{np})$$
while $RHS=\frac 1 {np}$. Hence $LHS\sim RHS$.

Comment: Nice one. Can you elaborate where the second-order term of E[1/B] comes from?

Comment: $E(g(X))\approx g(\mu)+\frac 1 2g''(\mu)\sigma^2$

Comment: @A.S. that looks nice, thank you. Could you explain how did you deal with $A$ and the $\min$?

Comment: @A.S. in general, I think $\min$ makes the LHS non-differentiable. Thus, Taylor expansion is problematic. Though, I did some simulation and RHS indeed well approximates LHS.

Comment: @math $P(B(n,p)<\frac 1 A)\to 0$ so you can choose arbitrary $A$ as it won't affect asymptotic behaviour - so choose $1$.

Comment: @A.S. but what if $A$ is very small, then there is quite a lot of weight in this probability? Or I don't understand something?

Comment: @math It doesn't matter how large *fixed* $1/A$ is. $P(B(n,p)<\frac 1 A)\to 0$ for all $A>0$.

Comment: Thank you @A.S. Do I understand correctly that the partial expectation that we have in the LHS $\mathrm{E}[\frac{1}{B(n,p)}; B(n,p)\geq 1/A]$ is also in the limit of $n\to\infty$ doesn't depend on $A$?

Comment: Yes. If $1/A<1$ you can instead use condition $B(n,p)\ge 1$ as I did above.